# Phoenix shows null values instead of real values stored in HBase after bulk load

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata, hbase, apache-phoenix

Phoenix shows nulls instead of actual values stored in hbase. When querying data in hbase everything is ok and all values are correct. Also, count operation shows correct number of rows in phoenix. But when querying any row, value of every column is null.

For loading data I used the same approach as here:

https://medium.com/hashmapinc/3-steps-for-bulk-loading-1m-records-in-20-seconds-into-apache-phoenix-99b77ad87387

At first I create phoenix table. Then I generate hfiles from spark dataset, store them at some temporary storage and bulkloade them into hbase table.

It works nicely with hbase but in phoenix all values are null.

To transform spark row values I used this:

```java
if (value instanceof String) {
    return PVarchar.INSTANCE.toBytes(value);
} else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
    return PBoolean.INSTANCE.toBytes(value);
} else if (value instanceof Double) {
    return PDouble.INSTANCE.toBytes(value);
} else if (value instanceof Float) {
    return PFloat.INSTANCE.toBytes(value);
} else if (value instanceof Long) {
    return PLong.INSTANCE.toBytes(value);
} else if (value instanceof Integer) {
    return PInteger.INSTANCE.toBytes(value);
} else if (value instanceof Short) {
    return PSmallint.INSTANCE.toBytes(value);
} else if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
    return PDecimal.INSTANCE.toBytes(value);
} else if (value instanceof Date) {
    return PDate.INSTANCE.toBytes(value);
} else if (value instanceof Timestamp) {
    return PTimestamp.INSTANCE.toBytes(value);
}
```

Comment: are there any conflicts on the data types ? I have had a case where we had a Phoenix column defined as an Integer and we had wrong data loaded on HBase when we wrote the data.

Comment: Didn't find any inconsistencies. It is strange because for any row it shows null values for all columns including primary key.

Comment: just out of curiosity , can you create a new view maybe with just the key and one more column and see how that comes up